# Cloned Code Not Working on SAme website from two different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Just Use to Clone Entire Div From Page 1 to Page 2 with the help of jquery ...Where

Page 2 Jquery Script

```
<script>
 $('#result').load('/admin/enquiry #container');
  </script>
```

Page 2 Page

```
<div class="box-body" id="result" >

</div>
```

on Page 1 Div

```
<div class="box-body" id="container" >Div Table Content....Here</div>
```

It's Cloning the whole table but the issue 
**In the table on page 1 there is edit & add button and its working fine on page 1 however buttons not working on page 2** 
**Looking for: a Cloned table to work as its working on Page 1**

**Note: All Pages are on the Same website...**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to also add the JS from page 1 in to page 2, using delegated event handlers as the content is dynamic. The simplest way to do that would be to put the code in to its own .js file and include it in both pages.

Comment: did it but not working